# ListView inside a Fragment gives error

Tags: android

I have issues in displaying ListView inside a Fragment. I am using ListFragment in my Fragment. I couldn't able to figure out where my actual issue is.

CategoriesFragment.java

```
public class CategoriesFragment extends ListFragment {  
ListView lv;
TextView tv;    
  public CategoriesFragment() {
  }    

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    if(container==null)
        return null;
    inflater.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_fragment,container,false);
    View listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    return view;        
  }    

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final String[] fruits = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
        "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit"};            
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (getActivity(),R.layout.categories_fragment,fruits));       
  }
}
```

PagerAdaper.java

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch(i) {
     case 0:
      Fragment fragment = new CategoriesFragment(); 
      return fragment;
      break;
     case 1:
      Fragment fragment = new FeaturedFragment(); 
      return fragment;
      break
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return 2;
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
      case 0: return "CATEGORIES";
      case 1: return "FEATURED";
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

categories_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/listview1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

DDMS error text:

```
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content        must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:895)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:772)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1234)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1017)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:555)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
09-06 12:37:47.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
```

Comment: In your logcat error is mention `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'` that means the id of your listview should be `android:id= "@android:id/list"`
`

Comment: Yes. That issue is resolved. Thanks. Getting another error. Trying to resolve myself before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listview1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

to,

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

The problem is with the ID. When you extend **ListFragment** your ListView must have id something like this, `@android:id/list`

Comment: Thanks @Selva.  It gives error at CategoriesFragment.java in this line,             `code` View listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview1);    I am not able to fetch the id of the listview now

Comment: I have changed it to android.R.id.list. That issue is resolved. But still some other issue is there. I am working on it.

Comment: Getting this error now. "arrayadapter requires the resource id to be a textview". Is that mean we can't pass a listview resuorce id in the adapter?

Comment: Thanks. Let me look into that.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `android:id="@+id/listview1"` use `android:id="android:id/list"`

because, `ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view. However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by returning your own view hierarchy from onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle). To do this, your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)`

Answer (score 1):

You already subclassed `ListFragment` and this already hosted a `ListView` object. Your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with the id `@android:id/list` instead of `@+id/listview1`