# java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Tags: android, listview

I know that there has been simialr questions but I can't make it work even though I look at those. The error message is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

. I have tried to change the id to list. In another. This what the code looks like:

```
 public class committeeFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    private CommitteeAdapter adapter;

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new CommitteeAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_committee, container, false);
    }

    public void
    refreshList() {
        adapter.updateDataSet();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

It's using the following adapter:

```
    public class CommitteeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private
    ArrayList<StudentCommittee> committeeList;
    private Context context;

    public CommitteeAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        CommitteeDatabaseAdapter dbAdapter = new CommitteeDatabaseAdapter(context);
        committeeList = dbAdapter.readAllCommittees();
    }

    public void updateDataSet() {
        CommitteeDatabaseAdapter dbAdapter = new CommitteeDatabaseAdapter(context);
        committeeList = dbAdapter.readAllCommittees();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        StudentCommittee committee = committeeList.get(position);

        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_committee, null);
        TextView sectionName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.committee_namn);

        sectionName.setText(committee.getName());
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return committeeList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public StudentCommittee getItem(int position) {
        return committeeList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Here is the xml-file that specifies the list(fragment_committee):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:tag="@string/tag_fragment_committee"
     android:background="@color/white" >

     <TextView
         style="@style/AppsolutText.Headline"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Festerier" />

      <View
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="2dp" 
         android:background="@drawable/divider_sliding_menu_item"/>

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <TextView 
         style="@style/AppsolutText.Normal"
         android:id="@android:id/empty"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="Uppdatera för att se en lista över festerier och fadderier. Kräver internetanslutning."/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the xml for the list item:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/committee_symbol"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="0"
         android:paddingBottom="10dp"
         android:paddingRight="10dp"
         android:paddingTop="10dp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/committee_namn"
         style="@style/AppsolutText.ListHeader"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

I hope that you can figure out what's wrong. I have another listview that has the same id (list) in another xml-file within the project. I don't know if that's a problem. Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView inside a Fragment gives error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294819/listview-inside-a-fragment-gives-error)

Comment: post your R.java class

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

you are adding a new id for your ListView but ListFragment needs a default Android ListView Id

change your ListView Id to :

> ```
> <ListView
>    android:id="@id/android:list"
>    android:layout_width="match_parent"
>    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
> ```

Comment: @Arash if we want to implement on click listener with this listview, then how can we achieve that?

Comment: @Alliswell : you have to override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
    {} . hope it helps

Comment: @Arash i would like to open child listview from each row without using adapter class. Can u give me an example for this

Comment: @Alliswell : See ExpandableListView , but i don't have any clue for your will without adapter Class!

Comment: @Arash using adapter in fragment can we achieve the same.. here i need the child views to be on the next layout not on the same..

Answer (score 5):

Change your `ListView` in XML to have the following id:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

It's a requirement of using `ListFragment`/`SherlockListFragment`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

> ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view. However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by returning your own view hierarchy from `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)`. To do this, your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or `list` if it's in code)

Comment: not need to use android for id.   android:id="@+id/listIdName" . it is also correct

Comment: If you use `ListFragment` you do, or else you will get errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean your project. If any xml releted error have , you can find it. Then you can change your list id . Find the list id are exist into your gen folder R.java class.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to stop using actionbarsherlock and use the support libraries instead to get action bar in Android 2.1 and above. After doing this, i got the "java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'". What i did to remedy this problem was

to read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#q=fragment

then change my fragment layout file from

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_detail"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    tools:context=".ItemDetailFragment" />
```

to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:paddingRight="8dp"
     tools:context=".ItemDetailFragment">

 <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#00FF00"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/item_detail"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

 <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#FF0000"
           android:text="No data"/>
```

... and voila, the RunTimeException with missing android.R.id.list was gone! Of course, i need to edit my new layout and fix it properly, but the key issue here was that i had overridden the fragment layout in its onCreateView method. ActionBarSherlock DID NOT have a problem with this, but with the Android support library, if u do this, you MUST have a ListView in your XML Layout, with the android:id="@id/android:list" as stated in the info linked to above.

Hope this helps (coming from a total newb in Android app dev)!

Comment: I would like to add to this info that since i was using ListFragment, i DID NOT have a ListView tag in XML anywhere, for this ListFragment. The ListView is built-in to the ListFragment but can be overridden. Therefore i could not just change the ListView android:id as many people suggest, because i could not find any ListView tags in XML related to my ListFragment. Hence the above solution - to add one!

Comment: Another comment to my own post above: I'm such a total newb to this and think i've used a ListFragment when i did not want a list in the first place. Makes sense that a ListFragment needs at least one ListView. I'm gonna use another type of Fragment so that i don't have to implement an unused ListView in my XML just to get rid of the RunTimeException. Gaah!